# No volume control after joining PulseAudio with Jack

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, volume-control, jack

I have installed and configured jackd server following the [Fedora's  Integrating PulseAudio with JACK tutorial](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Musicians_Guide/sect-Musicians_Guide-Integrating_PulseAudio_with_JACK.html).

The integration was successful. But now I'm not able to controll PulseAudio's volume using default ubuntu volume control nor the volume up/volume down media keys on my keyboard. Any change to said volume has no real effect. The sound level (for example youtube video in browser) does not change.

For now, the only working way of adjusting the volume level is through alsamixer. How can I bring back the default volume control?

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed [this tutorial](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/09/remapping-keyboard-multimedia-buttons-to-alsa-after-removing-pulseaudio/) on disabling the old keyboard shortcuts and creating new ones. At that link they use the multimedia keys to control the alsa mixer but I used it to control the pulseaudio mixer with
Volume up:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%
```

Volume down:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -10%
```

Mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle
```

This will only control pulseaudio volume though and ignore anything plugged directly into Jack. It also leaves you without the handy gui showing the volume level as you adjust it.